# Conditions in SparseArray

Tags: documentation, sparse-arrays

I got confused by `{i_, j_} /;` in the following code. I didn't see an explanation in the `SparseArray` documentation. Can anyone tell me how this part work in the code?

```
m1 = SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> -2, {i_, j_} /; Abs[i - j] == 1 -> 1}, {5, 5}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{i_, j_} /; Abs[i - j] == 1` is a pattern.  It matches pairs of expressions the difference of which is `1`.

`/;` is [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Condition.html).

In `SparseArray` this will put a 1 on the second diagonals, as the difference of the indices of elements on the second diagonals is `1` or `-1`.

Comment: @Szaolcs Thanks a lot!